# how to fix operator '==' is ambiguous on operands of type ulong and long

Tags: c#, sql, discord

I'm currently building a new command in my Discord Server and i'm struggling to convert the UserId back to the Users Nickname in my server.

i am getting error message operator '==' is ambiguous on operands of type ulong and long

Could someone help me figure out what i've done wrong

```
Int64 memberId = reader.GetInt64(0);
string name = Context.Guild.Users
    .Where(x => x.Id == memberId)
    .First()
    .Nickname != null 
        ? Context.Guild.Users.Where(x => x.Id = memberId).First().Nickname 
        : Context.Guild.Users.Where(x => x.Id = memberId).First().Username;
Int64 votes = reader.GetInt64(2);
GOTWVote.Add($@"{name} has received {votes} vote(s)");
```

Comment: `Where(x => x.Id = memberId)` this won't compile.

Comment: Where(x => x.Id = memberId) should be Where(x => x.Id == memberId).  You are using the assignment (=) operator, need to use comparator (==).

Comment: @Grant, That did the trick!, Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first step is to cast to resolve the ambiguous operator. Next, rearrange your query to get rid of the two extra subqueries:

```
Int64 memberId = reader.GetInt64(0);
var user = Context.Guild.Users
    .Where(x => x.Id == (UInt64)memberId)
    .First();

string name = 
    user.Nickname != null 
        ? user.Nickname 
        : user.Username;

Int64 votes = reader.GetInt64(2);
GOTWVote.Add($@"{name} has received {votes} vote(s)");
```

Comment: This also worked once i changed Uint to UInt

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the `.Where(x => x.Id = memberId)`, you should use `==` to compare instead of `=` (attribution) like you did before.

```
Int64 memberId = reader.GetInt64(0);
string name = Context.Guild.Users
    .Where(x => x.Id == memberId)
    .First()
    .Nickname != null 
        ? Context.Guild.Users.Where(x => x.Id == memberId).First().Nickname 
        : Context.Guild.Users.Where(x => x.Id == memberId).First().Username;
Int64 votes = reader.GetInt64(2);
GOTWVote.Add($@"{name} has received {votes} vote(s)");
```

But you could refactor this code to this (read to comments):

```
var memberId = reader.GetInt64(0);
// search for the user just a single time!
var user = Context.Guild.Users.First(x => x.Id == memberId);

// apply the rule to define the name string
string name = @string.IsNullOrEmpty(user.Nickname) ? user.Nickname : user.Username;

var votes = reader.GetInt64(2);
GOTWVote.Add($@"{name} has received {votes} vote(s)");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `memberId` to a `ulong` (or `UInt64`) so the type matches `x.Id`:

```
var memberId = (ulong)reader.GetInt64(0);
string name = Context.Guild.Users
    .Where(x => x.Id == memberId)
    ...
    ...
```

Also, you have a few other things to fix as the other answer and comments suggest. ;)